# Is it possible to edit the names of Bibtex entries on Google Scholar?

Tags: google-scholar

Question as in the title. If I have got a Bibtex entry such as

```
smith2019apples
```

can I change it to, say,

```
smith2019pie
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that this is specifically documented anywhere, but the answer is almost certainly no.

Article entries in Google Scholar, which contain the BibTeX link, are based on information crawled by Google on the web. This itself cannot be changed by you, even if you are the author. This is also mentioned in their [help page](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/help.html#corrections):

> The description of my article is wrong and I am appropriately
> irritated. How do I correct it?
>
> We apologize, and we assure you the error was unintentional. Automated
> extraction of information from articles in diverse fields can be
> tricky, so an error sometimes sneaks through.
>
> Please write to the owner of the website where the erroneous search
> result is coming from, and encourage them to provide correct
> bibliographic data to us, as described in the technical guidelines.
> Once the data is corrected on their website, it usually takes 6-9
> months to a year or longer for it to be updated in Google Scholar. We
> appreciate your help and your patience.

The articles on your profile, for which you can edit some fields, are connected to these existing Scholar entries.

It appears that Google Scholar uses the format `<last-name-of-first-author><year-of-publication><first-word-in-title>` for its BibTeX entry names. Since you cannot change the title in the original crawled Scholar entry (which would not make much sense in any case), it is unlikely that you can change the BibTeX entry name either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you export the `.bib` file, you can run a script (Python, Ruby, shell, other, your choice) over it to transform the name Goggle Scholar gave it to whatever format you want ***after you download it*** and before you check it into your source code repository. If this is something that you do frequently, a script is really the only way to go. This isn't necessarily easy. There are some parsing libraries out there, but they all seem to have some issues which you might have to fix or fix the output of (by hand or with another script).

What you can't do as @GoodDeeds points out, is change what Google Scholar calls it in their records since that's a programmatic construction itself that will consistently give it the name you are seeing until that code is changed by Google.